# Check if index of one array is equal to index of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, parallel-arrays

Basically I have two arrays, One containing 1-30 in french and the other containing 1-30 in english. What i've been trying to do is check if the user picks the right translation for the french number. This is done in the format of a select menu. 5 random numbers are used to pick 5 english words from the english word array and they are then put into a select menu. At the moment when I click submit guess, it will say every ENGLISH translation is the same as my French word!

#### Code Below:

```
number = random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30));
round = Math.round(number);
number = round;

function wordGen()
{
    var RanNumbers = new Array(6); //Holds the generated Numbers.

    for (var j = 0; j < RanNumbers.length; j++)
    {
        var temp = 0;
        do
        {
            temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
        }while (RanNumbers.indexOf(temp) > -1)

        RanNumbers[j] = temp;
    }
//Instead give user option of 5 answers to choose from
//Only one answer can be true.


foreignWords = new Array('un', 'deux', 'trois','quatre', 'cinq', 'six', 'sept','huit', 'neuf','dix','onze', 'douze', 'treize', 'quatorze','quinze','seize', 'dix-sept', 'dix-huit', 'dix-neuf', 'vingt', 'vingt et un','vingt-deux', 'vingt-trois', 'vingt-quatre', 'vingt-cinq', 'vingt-six', 'vingt-sept', 'vingt-huit', 'vingt-neuf', 'trente');

var translate = new Array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen', 'twenty', 'twenty-one', 'twenty-two', 'twenty-three', 'twenty-four', 'twenty-five', 'twenty-six', 'twenty-seven', 'twenty-eight', 'twenty-nine', 'thirty');


output = '';
randomWord = foreignWords[number];
correctAns = translate[number];

document.getElementById('generatedWord').innerHTML = randomWord;
var guessed = document.getElementById('guessed').value;
var guess = "<select name='guesses' id='guesses'>";
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
{

    guess += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + translate[RanNumbers[i]] + "</option>";

}
    guess += '<option value="6">'+correctAns+'</option';
    guess += "</select>";

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = guess;
    numGuessed = document.getElementById('guesses').value;

    //What I have tried ATM, THis will say every answer is correct! 
    document.getElementById('submitAns').onclick = function(){
            if(foreignWords.indexOf(number) === correctAns.indexOf(number)){
                alert("Correct");
            }
            else{
                alert('Incorrect'); 
            }



    }
}
```

#### I Have added the html for my code below:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <h2 style="color:rgba(0,153,204,1);">Guess what the generated french word translates to in English!</h2><br />

        <p align="center" id="generatedWord"></p>

        <input type="button" value="Generate Word" onClick="wordGen();" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="guessed" />
        <div align="center" id="output"></div>
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="submitAns" value="Submit Guess" />

    </div>
```

So at the moment my if statment says every english word is the correct answer. In my HTML page I only have 2 buttons, one to run the function (display french word and select menu) and the other button is to submit the guess. ***If I need to use jquery I will but i'd prefer to use plain javascript!

Comment: This type of question really needs a mockup. Can you provide sample HTML too?

Comment: Your page is something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Rhumborl/0u5pwddp/1/ I don't get what the `guessed` box is for tho

Comment: Is your code is running? because RanNumbers[i]] is called outside and you have defined it in function scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match the number (generated with random number) to translate array index as it is generating the output in foreign array and if it is matched the answer is correct.

```
function arrayValueIndex(arr, val){
    for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] === val) {
           return i;
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

and in your click event

```
document.getElementById('submitAns').onclick = function() {
   var 
       genWord = document.getElementById('generatedWord').textContent,
       select = document.getElementById('guesses'),
       selectedText = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
       number === arrayValueIndex(translate, selectedText) ? alert("Correct") : alert('Incorrect');
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zwemm70g/

Comment: I don't think there is a need to define another function to check if the seleted `option` exists in the array. The OP already creates a variable `correctAns` which stores the correct translation while the random number is generated which I think is efficient. We just need to check if the selected `option` is equal to the `correctAns` IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, since I'm not sure how you're displaying your foreign word and non-foreign words, however, I would think that:

```
numGuessed === number
```

Should work, since from what I can tell, `numGuessed` in the index of the word guessed, and `number` is the index of the word to be translated.

If that doesn't work, please clarify in your question how the HTML works, and let me know that you've edited and I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems I see with the logic of your code right away. I will mention them first.

1. You are trying to get the value of an element with `id` "guessed". There isn't any element with this id in your `html`. I'm assuming you are trying to get the value of the `select` element with `id` "guesses" but that again won't work since you create the element just after you try to get its value.

   ```
    var guessed = document.getElementById('guessed').value;
    var guess = "<select name='guesses' id='guesses'>"; 
    ...
   ```
2. The variables `randomWord` and `correctAns` are simple strings that you get out of the index `number` from both the arrays that you have created. So the following statement doesn't make sense:

   ```
   foreignWords.indexOf(number) === correctAns.indexOf(number)
   ```

It doesn't make sense because `correctAns` is a string and therefore it would try to attempt to give you the `index` of first occurence of `number` as a substring. `foreignWords` is an array and therefore there is clearly a mis-match here.

As a matter of fact, you just need to get this logic right, where you are asserting that the user has selected the right answer. You just need to get the `text` attribute of the selected `option` and try to see if that equals the `correctAns` variable. You can do that simply by this:

```
 document.getElementById('submitAns').onclick = function () {
   var x = document.getElementById("guesses").value; //get the index of selected option
   var guessed = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].text; //get the text of that option

    if (ans === correctAns) {
        alert("Correct");
    } else {
        alert('Incorrect');
    }

 }
```

I have created a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0u5pwddp/3/) incorporating this code snippet into your logic and seems to be working fine. Feel free to play around with it and I hope it gets you started in the right direction.

**Sidenote**- I see that you're adding the right answer i.e. `correctAns` always to the bottom of the `select` list like so: `guess += '<option value="6">'+correctAns+'</option';`. That's not random and for someone who uses your program, he/she might see the pattern in a few tries and not get a hang of English numbers :P.  Try to take that into account.

Comment: About the Sidenote - I totally agree but I don't know how to randomly add it into the select menu because I am using an array for the 'randomly generated options' and I have no other way of including the 'answer'. If you help me do that it would be much appreciated!

Comment: @James111, I would appreciate if you tell me why the answer was not accepted.

Comment: I just found the other answer easier to understand, I read through your's thoroughly and it explained things very well but when I tried fix my code up it wasn't working for me so I read one of the other answers and found it easier to implement! I'm new to coding so I'm not the best at implementing things and fixing code up! Learning is the best though :)

Comment: Sure @James111, whatever makes sense to you. Happy coding. :)